# Can't delete layout file after I created it in Next js

Tags: next.js, layout, runtime-error

In this screenshot, you can see the structure of my project. I am learning Next.js. I created a `layout.js` file in the `[id]` folder inside the `blog` folder just to test and try it. However, I have since deleted the `layout.js` file because I no longer need it.

[image]

But Next.js still looking for it and show this error for me:

> **./src/app/blog/[id]/layout.jsx
> Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\Dévelopement WEB\Tutorials\nextTuto\nextapplamadev\src\app\blog[id]\layout.jsx'**

Comment: I guess you need to restart your development server or rebuild your application

Comment: @SonamGupta I restarted the development server but with no result

Answer (score 0):

Delete the .next folder, restart the editor, restart server, open website in incognito. This might work.